# Java Generic Parameter Bound In Instantiation

Tags: java, generics

Having a major brain fart right now.

I have this:

```
public static final Map<WorkType, Class> handler;
```

Then

```
handler = new TreeMap<WorkType, Class>() {{
    put(WorkType.SUBMIT, UtilityHandler.class);
}};
```

Then

```
JobHandler jobHandler = instantiateHandler(handler.get(work), work, buildingId);
// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! this shows a warning unchecked assignment
// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
// Unchecked assignment: 'java.lang.Class' to 'java.lang.Class<? extends JobHandler>
```

Then

```
@SuppressWarnings(value="unchecked")
private static JobHandler instantiateHandler(Class<? extends JobHandler> ref, WorkType type, String id) {

    if(ref == null) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This action is not supposed!");
    }

    try {
        Constructor<JobHandler> constructor = (Constructor<JobHandler>) ref.getConstructor(WorkType.class, String.class);
        JobHandler handler = constructor.newInstance(type, id);
        return handler;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
        Utilities.writeLogException(null, e);
    }

    return null;

}
```

I want to get rid of unchecked assignment. I thought I could do this:

```
public static final Map<WorkType, Class extends JobHandler> handler;
```

But it is not allowed. Any thoughts/suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
Map<WorkType, Class<? extends JobHandler>> handler
```

Comment: Well, that was embarrassing. Thanks... I had it below, not sure why I thought it wouldn't work above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should declare

```
Map<WorkType, Class<? extends JobHandler>> handler
```

from the code inside the method `instantiateHandler` it looks like you are expecting a `Class` object of any subtype of `JobHandler` and you are trying to instantiate `JobHandler` object